# Locking thread and creating new cursors not resolving sqlite3 "recursive use of cursors not allowed"

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, flask, cursor

I am trying to make a simple flask web server that presents two graphs of data using matplotlib from a DHT22 sensor stored in a sqlite3 database. The code is based on that written by MRovai with a few changes (namely to resolve threading error messages):

https://medium.com/@rovai/from-data-to-graph-a-web-jorney-with-flask-and-sqlite-6c2ec9c0ad0

I assume there have been some changes to sqlite3 as I consistently receive "sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Recursive use of cursors not allowed" that obviously did not occur in MRovai's script.

I understand that sqlite 3 disallows sharing connections and cursors between threads have tried creating new cursors as well as locking as per:

[Python and sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Recursive use of cursors not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629080/python-and-sqlite3-programmingerror-recursive-use-of-cursors-not-allowed)

What I do not understand is how to correctly create a new cursor or lock for my particular code. Other examples elsewhere seem to be so different from my code as to not be comparable e.g.

[Recursive query with ordered values in SQLite Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509062/recursive-query-with-ordered-values-in-sqlite-android)

My code is below with attempts at locking the thread and creating a new cursor commented out to show what I have been trying.

Any help or hints greatly appreciated.

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import io
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file, make_response, request
app = Flask(__name__)
import sqlite3
#import threading

conn=sqlite3.connect('/home/pi/Documents/Sensors_Database/sensorsData.db', check_same_thread=False)
#conn2=sqlite3.connect('/home/pi/Documents/Sensors_Database/sensorsData.db', check_same_thread=False)
curs=conn.cursor()
#curs2=conn2.cursor()

#lock=threading.Lock()


# Retrieve LAST data from database
def getLastData():
        #lock.acquire(True)
        for row in curs.execute("SELECT * FROM DHT_data ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1"):
            time = str(row[0])
            temp = row[1]
            hum = row[2]
       # conn.close()
        return time, temp, hum
        #lock.release()

def getHistData (numSamples):
        #lock.acquire(True)
        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM DHT_data ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT "+str(numSamples))
        data = curs.fetchall()
        dates = []
        temps = []
        hums = []
        for row in reversed(data):
                dates.append(row[0])
                temps.append(row[1])
                hums.append(row[2])
        return dates, temps, hums
        #lock.release(True)

def maxRowsTable():
        for row in curs.execute("select COUNT(temp) from  DHT_data"):
                maxNumberRows=row[0]
        return maxNumberRows

# define and initialize global variables
global numSamples
numSamples = maxRowsTable()
if (numSamples > 101):
    numSamples = 100

# main route
@app.route("/")
def index():
        time, temp, hum = getLastData()
        templateData = {
                'time'  : time,
                'temp'  : temp,
                'hum'   : hum,
                'numSamples'    : numSamples
        }
        return render_template('index.html', **templateData)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    global numSamples
    numSamples = int (request.form['numSamples'])
    numMaxSamples = maxRowsTable()
    if (numSamples > numMaxSamples):
        numSamples = (numMaxSamples-1)
    time, temp, hum = getLastData()
    templateData = {
                'time'  : time,
                'temp'  : temp,
                'hum'   : hum,
                'numSamples'    : numSamples
        }
    return render_template('./templates/index.html', **templateData)

def plot_temp():
        times, temps, hums = getHistData(numSamples)
        ys = temps
        fig = Figure()
        axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        axis.set_title("Temperature [°C]")
        axis.set_xlabel("Samples")
        axis.grid(True)
        xs = range(numSamples)
        axis.plot(xs, ys)
        canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        output = io.BytesIO()
        canvas.print_png(output)
        response = make_response(output.getvalue())
        response.mimetype = 'image/png'
        return response

@app.route('/plot/hum')
def plot_hum():
        times, temps, hums = getHistData(numSamples)
        ys = hums
        fig = Figure()
        axis = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        axis.set_title("Humidity [%]")
        axis.set_xlabel("Samples")
        axis.grid(True)
        xs = range(numSamples)
        axis.plot(xs, ys)
        canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        output = io.BytesIO()
        canvas.print_png(output)
        response = make_response(output.getvalue())
        response.mimetype = 'image/png'
        return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=False)'''
```